# Sollin's algorithm in graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

What's is the Sollin's algorithm in graph theory?

Can you write pseudocode of this algorithm or explain how this algorithm work?

Comment: http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/12-mst.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sollin's algorithm is an algorithm for finding the Minimum Spanning Tree (MST) on a graph. Find more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bor%C5%AFvka%27s_algorithm).